# Do I have to recreate provisioning profiles if I create new App ID

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

Right now I want to create a new App ID for a new project. Do I have to recreate provisioning profiles for both development and distribution so new app id could work? By the way current provisioning profiles have App ID of "*". So this will be enough for all the app ids including the current and new one?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you are using *(wildcard), means that you are still in dev phase. So you can continue using your old wildcard provisioning for your new AppID too.

Note: If you have enabled stuff like push notifications in your new AppID, they wont work with the new provisioning.

But when you need to submit to store. You will have to create new provisioning for your new AppID.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm aware it's yes. `*` matches all IDs.

Answer (score 0):

For a development profile, you can (and are) using a wildcard app ID.  This will work for any apps you want to develop going forward, as long as you are not using certain special features, like push notifications, iCloud, etc.  This developement profile will let you run and debug your app on your test devices. Because of the wildcard app ID, you can use this existing profile to build new apps to your test devices.

If you plan to submit to the app store, you will meed an App Store Distribution Profile.  App store distribution profiles require explicit IDs in the profile.  This also helps guarantee uniqueness of app IDs within the iOS ecosystem.

I would recommend creating your explicit app ID to reserve your app's ID now, but leaving the developer profile configured to use the wildcard app ID. When you create a new app, you can continue to use the existing developer profile for the new app, but again when you want to submit the new app to the app store, you will need to create an explicit app ID and a new distribution profile with that app ID.